# Разбиение видео на массив изображений и обратно в Java

Tags: java, видео

Как разбить видео поток на массив из изображений в Java?
Например: Есть файл, или видео с ВебКамеры.
Как из этого получить набор BufferedImage, а потом обратно собрать в видео.
Интересуют какие нибудь библиотеки или просто примеры работы.

Comment: По логике нужно работать с кодеком этого видео и файлом. С помощью кодека разбиваете на кадры.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел библиотеку [xuggle](http://www.xuggle.com/). Позволяет довольно легко разбивать видео на изображения и потом собирать обратно в видео. 
Есть не мало примеров использования и понятный туториал.
[Еще пример на русском](http://programador.ru/video-audio-xuggle/)

Answer (score 2):

Все зависит от формата видео. Сначала, вам нужно декодировать видеопоток. Для этого неплохо подходит ffmpeg, благо биндинги для java [есть](http://fmj-sf.net/ffmpeg-java/getting_started.php). Потом каждый кадр обрабатываете как отдельное изображение.